# An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement. Workaround logic?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that i have used the structure of several times however I am now getting the message "An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.". I have researched this on the site but can't figure out how to get around it.

Can you help?

```
UPDATE AppTasks
SET AppTasks.Notes = CASE
                          WHEN notes LIKE '%Average Feedback is%' THEN notes
                          WHEN AVG(feedback * 1.0) < 2 THEN CONCAT('Average Feedback is Low 
    ', CAST(AVG(feedback * 1.0) AS decimal(5, 2)), ': ', notes)
                          WHEN AVG(feedback * 1.0) >= 2 THEN CONCAT('Average Feedback is High 
    ', CAST(AVG(feedback * 1.0) AS decimal(5, 2)), ': ', notes)
                          ELSE notes
                     END
FROM apptasks
WHERE frequency IN (2, 3, 4, 5)
  AND UserId = @UserId
  AND TimeRaised > GETDATE() - 1
  AND feedback >= 0.1;
```

Thanks,

Comment: You have an `AVG` expression in there, but no `GROUP BY` or `OVER` clause. Without knowing your actual goal, I can't tell you what the right answer is.

Comment: So it worked in a select statement when i entered the group by clause, what i'm looking to do is update a notes section of my data with the average feedback rating. There is a lot of other sql that is driving this, I could paste it but its very long